# Datatable Ajax reload not working on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I've been trying to work with a reload button that will load the datatable data, but whenever i press the button, the table is not reloading or not loading the new content.

Here's my code for Datatable

```
  var table = $('#m_table_1').dataTable({
        responsive: true,
        searchDelay: 500,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: 'http://digitalbulletinboard.xyz/bulletin/sample.php?getLostTable',
        columns: [
            {data: 'id'},
            {data: 'title'},
            {data: 'description'},
            {data: 'Actions'},
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: -1,
                title: 'Actions',
                orderable: false,
                render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                    console.log(data);
                    return `
                        <span class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="btn m-btn m-btn--hover-brand m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                              <i class="la la-ellipsis-h"></i>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="la la-edit"></i> Edit Details</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="la la-leaf"></i> Update Status</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="la la-print"></i> Generate Report</a>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                        <button type="button" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-brand m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" title="View" id="reload">
                          <i class="la la-edit"></i>


          </button>`;
            },
        }
    ],
});
```

And when clicking the reload button, I use this one

```
 $("#reload").click(function () {
        console.log("Reload");
        table.api().ajax.reload(null, false);
    });
```

Whenever i click the reload button. Nothing happens. is there a way to fix this? or something that I have done wrong?

I already tried but still nothing happens

```
 $('#m_table_1').dataTable().api().ajax.reload();
```

Edit 1:
Changed the reload to

```
table.ajax.processing(null, false);
```

and got stuck to this one.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention the version of DataTable you used. But for many cases situation you can try this one:

`table.ajax.reload( null, false );`

at least it works for latest version of DataTable.

Referenced from here: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: Did you try my code? `table.ajax.reload( null, false );` without `api()` or `processing()`

Comment: Thank you this works, I also edited my server side to match the problem.